# Ajax in .NET doesn't want to to load images as it should

Tags: javascript, image, download, xmlhttprequest

Every way I try to  obtain what I want with .NET and MSIE 8 desperately fails: Since I coulnd't manage to preload images with "GET", i decided to get them in base64: They came to the client side all right, but there I discovered MSIE8 can't manage base64 over 32Kb, so I'm down again.
So I came back to the classic method I found several times on the web, and there it goes:

```
var img = new Image();
var ajax = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
ajax.open("GET", url, false)
ajax.send(null);
var res = ajax.status;
if (res == 200)    // succès
{
    // this program crashes on next line as soon as 'url' points a jpg file
    var tx = rajax.responseText;
    // this program crashes on previous line except if 'url' points a text file
    img.src = tx;
}
```

So what can I do to be able to load my image this way ? thanks for your help.

Comment: `Since I coulnd't manage to preload images with "GET"` ... Huh?

Comment: Well, yes, the way I first tried is the one I'm back to, and this is the one coded above: Do you know qhy I get a "msxml3.dll: Erreur système : -1072896748." every time url is a jpeg file?

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the `src` property.

`src` takes a URL, not an actual image.
You don't need any AJAX.